# Posix regular expression in C

Tags: c, regex, linux, gcc, posix

I am working on this code where i have to compile some regular expression and use these compiled versions multiple times on different strings. So i decided to make a function where i could pass these compiled version for matching the string. My problem is that when i pass the compiled version in the function its showing a match but setting the regmatch_t structure fields to 0. However if i use them within the same function i am getting correct results.

```
void match_a(regex_t *a,char *str)
{
  regmatch_t match_ptr;
  size_t nmatch;
  regexec(a,str,nmatch,&match_ptr,0);
}
int main()
{
  regex_t a;
  regmatch_t match_ptr;
  size_t nmatch;
  char *str="acbdsfs";
  regcomp(&a,str,RE_EXTENDED);
  match_a(&a,str);
}
```

This is the general structure of the code.Please suggests any ways to debug this program

Comment: It might help to set `nmatch` to a sensible value, and possibly to provide a `regmatch_t` array capable of holding more than one result.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you understand how to use `regexec`. The `nmatch` argument tells `regexec` the number of `regmatch_t` objects you have provided. You haven't initialised the `nmatch` variable so it could be any indeterminate value, which will likely lead to a crash at some stage, or it may be `0` in which case the `regexec` function is defined to *ignore* the `pmatch` argument.

If you want only one `regmatch_t` result, try this:

```
void match_a(regex_t *a,char *str)
{
    regmatch_t match;
    size_t nmatch = 1;

    regexec(a, str, nmatch, &match, 0);
}
```

If you want up to 10 `regmatch_t` (for regular expressions with groups etc), try this:

```
void match_a(regex_t *a,char *str)
{
    regmatch_t matches[10];
    size_t nmatch = 10;

    regexec(a, str, nmatch, matches, 0);
}
```

For more information, read [this documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/regexec.html).

Comment: Thaks for the info. I was thinking about compiling the regex only once and then calling match_a multiple times for different values of str.
I think we cannot do that and have to regfree it everytime for a new string and compile all over again

Comment: @mayank_gupta: No, you can keep the `regex_t` variable and use it over and over, there is no problem with that.

Comment: Thanks. I tried reusing the regex_t by making the match function but the problem i am facing is that i am getting a segfault after executing regexec with the passed regex_t variable. It may be a silly mistake i have been stuck on it from some time. please help

Comment: int match(regex_t *exp,char *str)
{
 regmatch_t match_ptr;
 int flag;
 size_t nmatch=4;
 printf("%s \n",str);
 flag=regexec(exp,str,nmatch,&match_ptr,0);
 if(!flag)
 {
  printf("%d",match_ptr.rm_so);
 }
 return 0;
}

Comment: @mayank_gupta: The problem is that you are saying that you are providing 4 `regmatch_t` objects but you are actually only passing one. You need to provide four, so declare an array like my second example, e.g. `regmatch_t match_ptr[4]`

Comment: @dreamlax- your solution worked. Thanks a lot. This is the first time i am working on regex :)

Answer (score -1):

Why matches is not filled in position 1?

```
    regex_t a;
    regcomp(&a,"brasil",REG_ICASE);

    regmatch_t matches[2];
    size_t nmatch = 2;
    regexec(&a,"brasil brasil",nmatch,matches,0);

    int x;
    for(x=0;x<2;x++)
            printf("%i\n",matches[x].rm_so);
```

Comment: please post this a new question and not tag on to a previous question